# Can I have nested braces {{row.{{Columns[i].field}}}} in one *ngfor angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

```
<*ngFor="let row of Rows; let i = index">
```

I have two arrays and I need to show with columns order so I will

`get{{Columns[i].field}} then {{row.{{Columns[i].field}}}}`

Is that applicable or not. 
Is there any workaround for that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to make two ngfor to make it works

```
  `<tr *ngFor="let row of Rows">
    <td *ngFor="let column of Columns">
        {{row[column.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>`
```